# elements on the panel are displayed incorrectly When changing panels

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, wxwidgets

I am using **WxWidgets 3.2** for my **C++ Windows** application.
In my application I need to change the interface for the user when he clicks the buttons.

To change the interface, I use this idea: I show the desired panel using the Show() function and hide the rest of the panels using the Hide() function. Of course, I create the necessary panels in advance.

For example, here is the code for the main window of my application:

```
MainFrame.h
class MainFrame : public wxFrame {
public:
    MainFrame(const wxString& title);
    ~MainFrame();

private:
    LoginPanel * loginPanel;  // panel pointer 
    TablePanel * tablePanel;  // panel pointer

public:
    void ShowLoginPanel(); // function that displays the loginPanel
    void ShowTablePanel(); // function that displays the tablePanel
    void OnLoginEntered(wxCommandEvent& event); // to check the login
};
```

class implementation

```
MainFrame.cpp
MainFrameFrame::MainFrameFrame(const wxString& title)
    : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~wxRESIZE_BORDER) {
    wxBoxSizer* mainSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

    loginPanel = new LoginPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    tablePanel = new TablePanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    mainSizer->Add(loginPanel, 1, wxEXPAND);
    mainSizer->Add(tablePanel, 1, wxEXPAND);
    SetSizer(mainSizer);

    ShowLoginPanel();
}

void MainFrame::OnLoginEntered(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    auto login = event.GetString();
    if (login == CORRECT)
       ShowTablePanel();
}
void MainFrame::ShowTablePanel() {
    if (loginPanel != nullptr)
        loginPanel->Hide();
    if (tablePanel != nullptr) {
        tablePanel->Show();
    }
}
void MainFrame::ShowLoginPanel() {
    if (tablePanel != nullptr) {
        tablePanel->Hide();
    }
    if (loginPanel != nullptr)
        loginPanel->Show();
}
```

In this code, if the user entered the correct login, then I show the tablePanel and hide the loginPanel.

Here is the LoginPanel class code :

```
LoginPanel.h
class LoginPanel : public wxPanel {
public:
    LoginPanel(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY);

private:
    wxTextCtrl* usernameInput;
};

LoginPanel.cpp
LoginPanel::LoginPanel(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id)
    : wxPanel(parent, id) {
    wxButton* connectButton = new wxButton(loginTab, wxID_ANY, "Connect");
    connectButton->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &LoginPanel::OnConnectButton, this);
}
```

Here is the TablePanel class code :

```
TablePanel.h
class TablePanel : public wxPanel {
public:
    TablePanel(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY, const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
                     const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize, long style = wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, const wxString& name = wxPanelNameStr);

private:
    wxButton* backButton;
    wxGridSizer* tableGrid;

    wxPanel* CreateTableItemPanel(int tableNumber);
};

TablePanel.cpp
TablePanel::TablePanel(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxPoint& pos,
                     const wxSize& size, long style, const wxString& name)
        : wxPanel(parent, id, pos, size, style, name)
    {
        // Creating a back button
        backButton = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, "Back");

        // Create a grid of gaming tables
        tableGrid = new wxGridSizer(5, 4, 5, 5);

        // Adding multiple grid elements
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; ++i) {
            wxPanel* tableItemPanel = CreateTableItemPanel(i);
            tableGrid->Add(tableItemPanel, 0, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5);
        }

        // Placing elements on the gaming table selection panel
        wxBoxSizer* tableSelectSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
        tableSelectSizer->Add(backButton, 0, wxALIGN_LEFT | wxALL, 5);
        tableSelectSizer->Add(tableGrid, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5);

        this->SetSizer(tableSelectSizer);
}


wxPanel* TableSelectPanel::CreateTableItemPanel(int tableNumber){
        wxPanel* itemPanel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBORDER_SIMPLE);

        wxBoxSizer* itemSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

        // Create an image and add it to the grid
        wxBitmap bitmap; // Replace with real image
        wxStaticBitmap* bmpCtrl = new wxStaticBitmap(itemPanel, wxID_ANY, bitmap);
        itemSizer->Add(bmpCtrl, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wxALL, 5);

        // Creating text with information about the table
        wxString tableInfo = wxString::Format("Стол %d", tableNumber);
        wxStaticText* infoText = new wxStaticText(itemPanel, wxID_ANY, tableInfo);
        itemSizer->Add(infoText, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wxALL, 5);

        // Create a "Play" button and add it to the grid
        wxButton* playButton = new wxButton(itemPanel, wxID_ANY, "Play");
        itemSizer->Add(playButton, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wxALL, 5);

        itemPanel->SetSizer(itemSizer);
        return itemPanel;
}
```

The problem is that when changing panels, all elements in the displayed panel are shifted to the upper left corner.

[image]

If you stretch the panel to full screen, then all the elements are displayed correctly again. Why do items in the rendered panel display incorrectly when changing panels? And how can I fix it?

Comment: @joe_dawson, did you call `Layout()` after you placed all elements and assigned all sizers appropriately?

Comment: @Igor, I tried calling different functions: Layout(), Refresh(), but nothing worked.

Comment: @joe_dawson, how did you call it and where? You should call it right after `SetSizer()` call... Do you use any RAD tool or you wrote the code yourself? See if you can use the wxFormBuilder/wxCrafter/wxGlade to create the panel and run it. Also see if running the [anel code standalone works after adding Layout().

Comment: I called Layout() in the constructors of the MainFrame and TablePanel classes. Also I used the function: 
void ChessFrame::OnShow(wxMoveEvent& event) {
    event.Skip();
    
    if (loginPanel->IsShown()) {
        loginPanel->Refresh();
    }
    else if (tablePanel->IsShown()) {
        tablePanel->Refresh();
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, of course, implement this yourself, but what you describe seems an awful lot like [wxSimplebook](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/classwx_simplebook.html), so perhaps you could just use this class instead?

Comment: This is a very good class)) Thanks, your solution works.

Comment: Now all pages have the same size equal to the size of the largest of the added pages. Can you tell me how to set different sizes for wxSimplebook pages?

Comment: It doesn't support this, all pages always have the same size which is equal to the size of the control. You could resize the control when switching pages but this would probably look strange, it's usually better to keep the same size for the UI.

Comment: Of course, you are right, but first I need to show the user a small window (480x320) in which he will enter his login and password, and after that I need to show a large window (1024x768) in which there will be various wxSimplebook pages. How can I solve this problem with wxwidgets ?

Comment: If you want it to be inside the same top level window, the best seems to just center your small window in it. Otherwise you could also use different top level windows, i.e. a dialog for entering the password, but personally I think it looks worse.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `Layout()` after calling `SetSizer()`.

This call will set up the (lay out) the controls according to you sizers structure.